# Concatenate existing href with a url before the text

Tags: javascript

I am currently looking for a way to concatenate the string an href holds with another.
I grab the texts using an REST-endpoint:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="schnittstelle-01"></div>
</body>

<script> const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET","http://exist.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de:8080/exist/restxq/edoc/collection/religionsfrieden/nav.html");
    request.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
       if (request.status = 200 ) {
          document.getElementById("schnittstelle-01").innerHTML = request.responseText;
          console.log(request.responseText);
       }
    });
    request.send(); 

</script>
</html>
```

The request.responseText text, however, only takes the "specific part" as a url:

```
view.html?id=e000001_kuttenberger_religionsfrieden_tschech
```

which, at least in my local dev-environment brings me to localhost:5050/view.html/...
This makes total sense but does not really help me.

I need a way to make all the hrefs inside the div#schnittstelle-01 lead to someUrl+view.html?id=e000001_kuttenberger_religionsfrieden_tschech , where the second bit is taken from the request.responseText

I'd prefer JS-only solutions, if there are any.

I have tried using suggestions from [here](https://javascriptio.com/view/231470/javascript-concatenate-variable-to-url)

any help would be appreciated,
K

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var el of document.querySelectorAll("#schnittstelle-01 a"))
    el.href = "https://yoursite.com/" + el.href;
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your immediate response :-) 
This does, at least in my  setup, not change the localhost:5050 part but rather append my URL upfront. It now looks like this: 
```http://exist.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de:8080/exist/apps/edoc/http://127.0.0.1:5500/view.html?id=e000001_kuttenberger_religionsfrieden_tschech``` 

How would I address that issue?

Comment: You could use `el.href = el.href.replace(window.location.origin, "https://yoursite.com/")`

Comment: still not it, I am afraid:
```http://exist.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de:8080/exist/apps/edoc//view.html?id=e000001_kuttenberger_religionsfrieden_tschechhttp://127.0.0.1:5500/view.html?id=e000001_kuttenberger_religionsfrieden_tschech``` 
I canno get the localhost out of there ?

edit: My bad: caching was active - sorry that was stupid :-D

Comment: @kev1807 Please check the links first. Your example clearly shows that it works (because there's a duplicated `//` before `view.html`: `.../edoc//view.html?...`), hence the links are already broken before you call `.replace(...)`